# C# - DataGridView with Wrap text in Cell but without spaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have used the DataGridView with the line break but for some reason something is wrong.
This is the code:

```
this.übersetzerDataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCellsExceptHeaders;
this.übersetzerDataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Here is the result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you adding the linebreak? Using `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: The dataGridView is populated from the database and the only code I use for line wrap is the one I just mentioned above. The strangest thing is that lines 1,2,3 and 4 are normal. If the text is small, everything is normal too. Weird.

Comment: Does the data from your database contain any linebreaks in the text?

Comment: No. In the database I have not line breaks

Comment: In the image it looks like there are other columns to the right. Is the text wrapping in any of those columns causing the row height to increase?

Comment: Yes, there are 2 more columns to the right. The 1ª  is the English translation and the 2ª is an icon.

Comment: Are either of those columns wraps to a new line within the cell?

Comment: No, they are all independent.
As I said, the strangest thing is if you reduce the size of the text, everything gets normalized.

Comment: Give us code that reproduces it for us.  You're making everyone guess at the problem.

Comment: What code do you want to see? My problem is when I enter those two lines above.

Comment: Start a new project, add a grid, give us the bare minimum code that reproduces the problem in that project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**SOLVED**] After much searching, I finally found the solution.

By using **Fill** value in the column in question.

> The column width adjusts so that the widths of all columns exactly fills the display area of the control.

```
 this.übersetzerDataGridView.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;         
 this.übersetzerDataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders;         
 this.übersetzerDataGridView.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Since @Michael posted his code in German and it might make some people confused (just like me) this did the work for me -

> Add the following code to the RowValidated event in your DataGridView

```
Private Sub DGV_RowValidated(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV_I.RowValidated
    DGV_I.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
    DGV_I.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
    DGV_I.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
End Sub
```

The result -

[image: DGV Wrap]

Answer (score -1):

1. Enable wrap mode for the column in question:

   `dgv.Columns["dtComment"].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;`
2. Set **AutosizeRowsMode** to **AllCells**